# Require.JS + Backbone + "Crockfords" Model Pattern

Tags: requirejs

CONDITIONS:

1) We have a bunch of legacy code that uses the following pattern:

base.js

```
var Base = function(config) {
    var that={};
    that.doThing1=function(){};
    that.doThing2=function(){};
    return that;
}
```

child.js

```
var Child = function(config) {
    var that=Base;
    that.doStuff1=function(){that.doThing1();};
    that.doThing2=function(){};
    return that;
}
```

2) One of the most important things about this is that it is legacy code, and lots of it, so refactoring everything to use a different pattern is *totally* out of the question for now.

3) I am trying to use require.js for the current project, along w/backbone, and so have child class where I want to require the "Base" dependencies.

This is where I am now, but it is not working:

```
require('Base'), function(Base) {
    var Child = function(config) {
        var that=Base;
        that.doStuff1=function(){that.doThing1();};
        that.doThing2=function(){};
        return that;
    }
    return Child;
}
```

QUESTION(S):

How do I set up this pattern so that I can wrap a require() around it that grabs the legacy dependencies asynch so that I can then require() Child into the backbone classes?

Comment: Oops, for the last one I meant: 
    require(['Base'], function(Base) {...return Child});

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this seems to do it. The thing that threw me is - notice in base.js that the name of the class isn't there. Instead, I named it in the require.config().

base.js

```
define(function() {
    return function(config) {
        var that={};
        that.doThing1=function(){};
        that.doThing2=function(){};
        return that;
    };
});
```

child.js

```
define(['Base'], function(Base) {
    return function(config) {
        var that=Base(config);
        that.doStuff1=function(){that.doThing1();};
        that.doThing2=function(){};
        return that;
    };
});
```